# only one form tag inside content placeholder in the child page

Tags: asp.net, html

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContent" runat="server">
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </form>
    </asp:Content>
```

I have different moduals and I was new folder in my project makes master page then when i remove the form tag it show error to add textbox in form tag.  help me

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017 u can use contentplaceholder without form tag. Use asp.net 4.6.2